# Resizing SunAwtFrame

Tags: windows, awt

There is an application written in Java using [AWT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_Window_Toolkit). And I want to resize its windows by an external program. My OS is Windows XP. Actually this application is an online poker client.

The windows are of "SunAwtFrame" class, so I look for those windows and call MoveWindow/SetWindowPos on them. The result is not the one I expect:

[a problem http://savepic.net/1331700.png](http://savepic.net/1331700.png)

As you see, the window did resize, but the content did not. While resizing manually it scales, and I want the same behavior here.
Probably, some additional action are needed to make AWT windows understand it was resized.
How can I fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend doing this:

- Use Spy++ (available as a tool in Microsoft
  Visual Studio) to filter messages sent to the SunAwtFrame window.
- Resize window manually.
- Figure out which messages are sent to the window during resizing. Use
  MoveWindow/SetWindowPos and/or send those messages after you resize.
- Take a look at functions InvalidateRect and UpdateWindow.